# iframe responsive, width working incorrect

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, responsive

I've testing responsive in iframe, my code look like this.

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
    <iframe src="http://revzilla.com" height="1600px" width="100%" frameborder="0" style="padding: 0; maring: 0; border: 0"></iframe>
</body>
```

But it does not render like when i open the url directly.

See images.

**First image:** Use iframe.

[image: Open with iframe]

**Second image:** Open directly.

[image: Open directly]

**Question 1:** How can I modify CSS for iframe to make it render like the same as when i open the url directly.

**Question 2:** If i can accesses content in the iframe (html document on iframe). How can I modify CSS on that document without modify iframe.

Comment: In you're site use bootstrap or something similar?

Comment: Do you perhaps have some wrapper around iframe? Also, by following [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in your question, you are more likely to get faster and better answer.

Comment: @CordovanSaviour I don't have any wrapper around iframe.

Comment: What does your developer tools inspection say? Try adding more code in your question.

Comment: @CordovanSaviour, I've edit this post and add more code (on the iframe side). PS. The link in the src of iframe is not mine.

Comment: @CordovanSaviour, I've edit this post and add more code (on the iframe side). PS. The link in the src of iframe is not mine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114682/discussion-between-taev-and-cordo-van-saviour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you included a `meta` `viewport` tag on the source of the iframe and the file itself?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Remember that the literal pixel width depends on the user's device pixel ratio, so if you are viewing on retina devices where the device pixel ratio is above 1 then the amount of pixels will scale with it.

Comment: I try something like your suggestion with this site http://www.kingpower.com/en/. It's not working, just like http://revzilla.com.

Comment: Do you have a like example? I can't see an iframe, like one in your original post, in that link

Comment: Also try settings the `initial-scale` to `2` instead of `1` since I assuming you are using an iOS device with a dpr of 2

Comment: I've try settings initial-scale to 2. It's still not working.

Comment: Do you have a live example?

Comment: You say the link in the source of your iframe is not yours, are you able to edit the HTML? The above HTML I mentioned needs to go into the source page.

Comment: I have no live example. But you can copy my code and paste on the text file, save it as .html file, then open with chrome (or any browser).

Comment: Have you added the `meta` `viewport` tag to your parent file?